# Schedule/cron MS Outlook to run rules

Tags: script, microsoft-outlook-2010, cron, rules

I have a ton of rules configured for my MS Outlook account.  However, I'd like to create a "Cleanup Rule" that deletes messages in various folders. I'd like this rule to run every day at a certain time, or at least every time I sign in (if the former isn't possible). Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What criteria are you wanting to use to delete them? Messages older than x days? Also, what version of outlook?

Comment: Thanks @Simkill (+1) - I'd say delete anything in the folder named "`widgets/`" that is 2 days old; also this is Outlook 2010. Thanks again!

Comment: Again, I'm also okay if the rule runs automatically everytime I log in. Just looking for a way to run the cleanup rule without having to do anything manually.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using autoarchive to gather everything for you then manually delete the contents of the archive file, but that isn't an answer as it's still manual work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I think you can do it with auto-archive after all. Go to file/options/advanced, click 'AutoArchive settings...'

Set for every 1 days, tick delete expired items, tick archive or delete old items, then hit the permanently delete old items radio button. Also set clean out items that are older than2 days. Try that and see how you go.

Comment: Worked perfectly :-) only correction is that the correct path is `Tools Menu >> Options >> Other Tab` instead of `File >> Options >> Advanced`. Other than those minor details, this worked great - thanks!